# Apps not showing in Django admin site

Tags: python, django, model, admin

I have a Django project with about 10 apps in it. But the admin interface only shows Auth and Site models which are part of Django distribution. Yes, the admin interface is up and working but none of my self-written apps shows there.

**INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'project.app1',
    ...
```

**app1/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from project.app1.models import *

admin.site.register(model1)
admin.site.register(model2)
admin.site.register(model3)
```

What could be wrong in this case? Looks like everything is configured as what document says.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I sometimes get this problem too. Emptying the browser cache and restarting the server seems to help. After restarting the server, it seems to also take a few minutes to properly load the admin modules.

Comment: Hello guys, I have same problem with 1.2.4 version, all looks be configured done and on localhost with dev server all works correct, but deployed on apache / mod_wsgi I see nothing, intersting is, that all applications works fine, but are not manageble in admin

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Django are you using?  Support for files named admin.py was added in version 1.0 (I think).  Before that, you'd have to add [extra information to your model](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/tutorial02/).

Comment: @zach, i'm using latest django version from development trunk.

Answer (score 0):

If something in your app throws an exception, the app or model may be excluded from the admin on subsequent requests.

If that is the case, you should get an error on the first request.

Also, please make sure your URLCONF has admin.autodiscover()

Comment: yes admin.site.autodiscover() is the most important thing to check. this is the command which actually loads your admin.py files from the app directories.